# If $A$ is self-adjoint, how are $\inf\sigma(A)$ and $\inf_{\left\|x\right\|_H=1}\langle Ax,x\rangle_H$ related?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, spectral-radius

Let $H$ be a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space, $A\in\mathfrak L(H)$ be self-adjoint, $r(A)$ and $\sigma(A)$ denote the spectral radius and spectrum of $A$, respectively, and \begin{align}\lambda_{\text{min}}&:=\inf\sigma(A),\\\lambda_{\text{max}}&:=\sup\sigma(A),\\m&:=\inf_{\left\|x\right\|_H=1}\langle Ax,x\rangle_H,\\M&:=\sup_{\left\|x\right\|_H=1}\langle Ax,x\rangle_H.\end{align}

I know that $$r(A)=\left\|A\right\|_{\mathfrak L(H)}=\max_{\lambda\in\sigma(A)}|\lambda|=\max(-\lambda_{\text{min}},\lambda_{\text{max}})\tag1.$$ On the other hand, $$\left\|A\right\|_{\mathfrak L(H)}=\sup_{\left\|x\right\|_H=1}|\langle Ax,x\rangle_H|=\max(-m,M)\tag2.$$

> **Question 1**: From $(1)$ it should follow that at least one of $\lambda_{\text{min}}$ and $\lambda_{\text{max}}$ is contained in $\sigma(A)$. In the same way, by $(2)$ it should follow that at least one of $m$ and $M$ is contained in $\sigma(A)$. Or am I missing something?
>
> **Question 2**: How are $\lambda_{\text{min}}$, $\lambda_{\text{max}}$, $m$ and $M$ related? It's tempting to expect that $\lambda_{\text{min}}=m$ and $\lambda_{\text{max}}=M$, but can we actually show that?

Comment: Both Q1 and Q2 are correct, for Q2 see the [min-max theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Self-adjoint_operators).

Comment: @Conifold Do you've got a reference for this theorem? I've searched in Rudin for it, but couldn't find it.

Comment: Wikipedia references [Teschl's Mathematical Methods
in Quantum Mechanics](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-schroe/schroe.pdf), freely available. Your Q2 is Theorem 2.19, p.77.