# A step in the proof of the Spectral Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

Let $T\in \mathcal{L}(H)$ be a compact self-adjoint operator on a separable Hilbert space $H$ over $\mathbb{R},$ and denote $||-||_{op}$ the operator norm; the context for the question is that I am reading a proof of the spectral theorem, where there are two things claimed without proof:

> a) that given an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $T,$ we have $\left| \lambda \right|\leq ||T||_{op};$
>
> b) that at least one of $\text{inf}_{u\in H, ||u||=1}(Tu,u)$ or $\text{sup}_{u\in H, ||u||=1}(Tu,u)$ is an eigenvalue of $T.$

Can you show me a proof of these claims? Are these standard facts?

**Edit**

Since, as mentioned in the comments (which I thank), these are standard facts, can someone at least provide me a reference that contains a proof of point (b)?

**Edit '**

> I managed to prove that both $\text{inf}_{u\in H, ||u||=1}(Tu,u)$ and $\text{sup}_{u\in H, ||u||=1}(Tu,u)$ are actually contained in the spectrum $\sigma(T),$ but I know that not all elements of the spectrum are eigenvalues; so how does one prove that at least one of the two is an eigenvalue?

Comment: For $a)$ just invoke the definition of operator norm as a supremum over unit vectors, and the result should follow.

Comment: Indeed if $Tf = \lambda f$ where $\|f\|=1$ then $$\|Tf\| = \|\lambda f\| = |\lambda\|f\| = |\lambda| \leqslant \|T\|,$$ as $$\|T\| = \sup_{\|f\|=1}\|Tf\|. $$

Comment: Both are standard results. For b) see [If $A$ is self-adjoint, how are $\inf\sigma(A)$ and $\inf_{\left\|x\right\|_H=1}\langle Ax,x\rangle_H$ related?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3491868/152568)

Comment: @Conifold thank you, but the link you refer to has no answers and no proofs in it, unless I am missing something. Even the book that is referred to in the comments gives only the claim without proof.

Comment: Theorem 2.19 is a trivial consequence of Theorem 2.18 proved in the book.

Comment: @Conifold Thanks, see my edits

Comment: For [compact operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theory_of_compact_operators#Compact_operators) every non-zero spectral value is an eigenvalue.

Comment: @Conifold OK, then I proved that both are spectral values, and so to prove that at least one is an eigenvalue, I need to prove that at least one is non-zero; but this follows from the fact that we suppose $T$ to be non-zero, and so ||T|| is non-zero. Thus at least one of the two is non zero since we can prove that ||T|| is equal to the maximum of these two. Right?

Comment: Yes. More generally, a self-adjoint operator with only zero in the spectrum is zero.

Answer (score 1):

If $T$ is a compact self-adjoint operator on a non-zero Hilbert space $H$ and
$$
m(T) = \sup\{\langle Tf,f\rangle:f\in H, \|f\|\leqslant 1\},
$$
then either $m(T)$ or $-m(T)$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.

Note first that since $T=T^*$, we have for $f,g\in H$ $$\langle Tf, g\rangle = \langle f, Tg\rangle, $$
and setting $f=g$ we have $$\langle Tf, f\rangle = \overline{\langle f,Tf\rangle} = \langle f,TF\rangle,$$
so that $\langle Tf,f\rangle\in\mathbb R$, so that the absolute value $|\cdot|$ is not needed in the definition of $m(T)$. If $m(T) = 0$ then by the polarization identity we have for each $\|f\|=1$
$$
\langle Tf, f\rangle = \frac14(\|Tf+f\|^2 - \|Tf-f\|^2 + i\|Tf -if\|^2 -i\|Tf+if\|^2)= 0,
$$
from which
$$
4\mathrm{Re}(\langle Tf,f\rangle) = \|Tf+f\|^2 - \|Tf-f\|^2 = 0,
$$
hence
\begin{align}
\|Tf+f\|^2 = \|Tf-f\|^2 &\implies \langle Tf+f,Tf+f\rangle = \langle Tf-f,Tf-f\rangle\\
&\implies \|Tf\|^2 + \langle Tf,f\rangle + \langle f,Tf\rangle + \|f\|^2 = \|Tf\|^2  - \langle Tf, f\rangle - \langle f,Tf\rangle + \|f\|^2\\
&\implies 2\langle Tf,f\rangle = -2\langle Tf,f\rangle\\
&\implies \langle Tf,f\rangle = 0.
\end{align}
It follows that $T=0$.

Assume then that $|m(T)|>0$. Replacing $T$ by $-T$ as necessary, define $\varphi:H\to\mathbb R$ in $H^*$ by $\varphi(f) = \langle \varphi f,f\rangle$. Let $B = \{\psi\in H^*: \sup_{\|f\|=1}|\psi(f)| \leqslant 1\}$ be the closed unit ball in $H^*$. Since $H$ is separable, let $\{f_n\}$ be a countable dense subset. Then the following $\rho$ defines a metric on $B$:
$$
\rho(\varphi,\psi) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}\frac{|\langle \varphi - \psi,\varphi_n\rangle|}{1+|\langle \varphi-\psi,\varphi_n\rangle|}.
$$
By the sequential Banach-Alaoglu theorem, $B$ is sequentially compact under $\rho$ - we may see this by a diagonalization argument similar to the one employed in the proof of the Arzelà–Ascoli theorem. Therefore by reflexivity of $H$, the closed unit ball $B$ is weakly compact. Also, the compactness of $T$ means that $T:(H,\text{ weak topology})\to (H,\text{ norm topology})$ is continuous, so $\varphi$ is continuous on $B$ equipped with the weak topology, and thus attains its maximum $m(T)$ at some $\psi\in B$. By maximality, $\|\psi\|=1$, which implies that $\psi$ maximizes the Rayleigh quotient $f\mapsto \frac{\langle Tf,f\rangle}{\langle f,f\rangle}$, from which we see that $T\psi = m(T)\psi$, thus proving the claim.

Comment: Thanks very much, but it looks like you are proving a slightly different claim than the one I asked about. This is the claim that one founds in wikipedia.

Comment: You have changed your question! But still my answer shows that $m(T)$ (or $m(-T) = -m(T))$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I'm not seeing something stupid, but the answer you gave solves a problem different from my first original question. Your definition of $m(T), -m(T)$ isn't slightly different from my inf and sup? How to get my from yours to mine?

Comment: They are the same. Consider that a compact self-adjoint operator need not be positive (i.e. $\langle Tf, f\rangle\geqslant 0$ for all $f\in H$). As for the domain of $f$, it makes no difference whether we consider the closed unit ball $\|f\|\leqslant 1$ or the closed unit circle $\|f\|=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Because your operator is compact, its spectrum consists of eigenvalues, with the only possible exception of $0$. And if zero is not an eigenvalue, then the spectrum is a sequence that converges to zero.

So if your sup and inf are distinct (and they always are unless $T=0$) then at most one of them can be zero, and so the other one is an eigenvalue.

As for your first question, if $Tx=\lambda x$, then 
$$
\lambda=\lambda\,\frac{\langle x,x\rangle}{\|x\|^2}=\frac{\langle \lambda x,x\rangle}{\|x\|^2}=\frac{\langle Tx,x\rangle}{\|x\|^2}\leq\frac{\|Tx\|\,\|x\|}{\|x\|^2}\leq\frac{\|T\|\,\|x\|^2}{\|x\|^2}=\|T\|.
$$